# How to determine and set android.process.media group?

Tags: android, linux, shell

Android has a system media service, which process name is `android.process.media`. It has `sharedUserId=android.media`, and id of process itself is simply `app_xx`. In the absence of the shell commands `groups`, `useradd`, and proper-functional `id` i don't have any idea how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

- to determine android.process.media GIDs look at the ActivityManager log which contains them.
- To add a new GID add it as a permission: first a new value in "android_filesystem_config.h", then a permission in AndroidManifest.xml of base frameworks and finally assign it to the target in "permissions.xml".

Android platform uses a hard-coded list of user and group IDs which is stored in the file called "android_filesystem_config.h".

Most of system services have the same gids as SystemServer process which GIDs are hard-coded in it's main() function in Zygote.

Additional GIDs are mapped in permissions.xml to Android permissions. There're also special permissions for ADB root user, Media service, etc. are set in this file.